# How to insert symbols like em dash, ® or ™ in refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms, wymeditor

I'm trying to figure out how to add the ability to add symbols like an em dash, ® or ™ in the wymeditor in refinerycms.  Looking at the boot_wym.js.erb there doesn't appear to be an option to enable it in the menu.  Does anyone know if it is possible and how you would do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ugly hack:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/refinery-cms/xiQfYNuWLOs